# Focusing on a field rendered via jQuery Mobile 'enhanceWithin()'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I came across a little irritating problem today, whilst attempting to focus on an input field that has been built and then enhanced (The form container '$selectedActionsContainer' is passed to '.enahnceWithin();').

Doesn't work:

```
$selectedActionsContainer.enhanceWithin();
$userInputNewBoxes.focus();
```

Works:

```
$selectedActionsContainer.enhanceWithin();
setTimeout(function(){
    $userInputNewBoxes.focus();
}, 50);
```

I've had a look at the jQuery Mobile documentation, and looked around for any people experiencing similar problems but couldn't find anything (Very possible I have missed the explaination).

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this, and if there is a better solution (there must be one...) than 'setTimeout()'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.enhanceWithin()` method is acting on all newly inserted elements, so I wouldn't rely on, or make any assumption, about what it will be inside the container, nor how long it will take to initialize all the new widget instances. For sure, the browser will need some time to reflow and to attach new events.

If you need an alternative solution, Ypu can trap the JQM `textinputcreate` event. Here is an example:

```js
function enhance() {
  var html = '';
  html += '<div class="ui-field-contain" data-mini="true">';
  html += '<label for="basic">Text Input:</label><input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value="">';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '<div class="ui-field-contain" data-mini="true">';
  html += '<label for="search-1">Search Input:</label><input name="search-1" id="search-1" value="" type="search">';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '<div class="ui-field-contain" data-mini="true">';
  html += '<label for="textarea-1">Textarea:</label><textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-1" id="textarea-1">Textarea</textarea>';
  html += '</div>';
  $(document).one("textinputcreate", "#basic", function(e) {
    this.focus();
  });
  $("#container").empty().append(html).enhanceWithin();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page-1" data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-mini" onclick="enhance(); return false">Enhance & Focus</a>
      <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```